# Writing to CSV file in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, csv

I have looked far and wide but I can't find any resources on how to write to CSV files from flash AS3. 
I know that flash cannot write to it alone. I have used PHP before to write to a txt file but now I need to open a csv and insert/edit entries that are already in it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

There is no built in support for CSV, although it can be done manually:

```
//dummy data
var data:Array = [];
for(var i:int = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) data[i] = {a:Math.random() * 100,b:Math.random() * 100,c:Math.random()};
//make a csv string
var csv:String = '';
for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) csv += data[i].a + ',' + data[i].b + ',' + data[i].c+'\n';
//write to disk
stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,writeCSV);
function writeCSV(event:MouseEvent) {
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes.writeUTFBytes(csv);
    file.save(bytes,'test.csv');
}
```

Still, there is an [as3 csv library](http://code.google.com/p/csvlib) out there.

> I need to open a csv and insert/edit entries that are already in it.

Have a look at **Data functions and manipulations** on the [csvlib wiki](http://code.google.com/p/csvlib/wiki/QuickStart).

HTH

Comment: Thanks this works but I don't want it to be done manually. I used PHP instead. I posted the variables to the php code and searched the CSV file from there and inserted the data appropriately :)